# Set a background sound for conference call

Tags: lync, lync-2010, lync-2013, lync-server-2010

Is it possible to set a background sound for a person while he/she is in a conference call alone, but once somebody else joins, the sound will be turned off? I don't think there needs to be any deeper explanation as the question is stating the problem exactly as it is.

A hint where to look for it, where to start would be very useful.

Thanks!